# Display trailing spaces in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to have a nice and sweet display of trailing white-space in my terminal vim. This would allow me to remove them before closing the file.

I am aware that this question is quite popular and I already found dozens of answers on SO. Unfortunately I did not found a satisfying one yet...

So I will try to summarize the gathered information and the solutions I found.

### Solution 1: Manually highlight trailing spaces

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

[image: Highlight trailing whitespaces]

Pros:

- Easy to use
- Fast
- Compatible with `cursorline`

Cons:

- Chosen color not compatible with other color schemes because color is manually set to `red`
- Big red background blocks are not very esthetic

### Solution 2: Using list feature

```
set list
set listchars+=trail:◦
```

[image]
[image]

Pros:

- Easy to use
- Fast

Cons:

- Issue if `:set cursorline` enabled
- Dedicated color for `list/trail` is not configurable. Has to be the same as the other listchars

### Solution 3: Using conceal feature

```
syn match WhiteSpace "\s\+$" containedin=ALL conceal cchar=◦
set conceallevel=2 
set concealcursor=nv
highlight Conceal ctermfg=red
```

[image]
[image]

Pros:

- Prettier than the first solution

Cons:

- Background is not the same as the cursorline background
- May interfere with other conceal rules
- Chosen color not always compatible with the color scheme
- Not compatible with older version of Vim

### My question

> Which one of the enumerated solutions is the most suitable in terms of
>   performance and compatibility and how can I get all the pros and none
>   of the cons?
>
> In other terms, I would like to find a solution where:
>
> - The highlight trailing color agree with the chosen colorscheme
> - This color is clearly visible but not too aggressive to the eyes
> - Compatible with `cursorline` (background and foreground)`
> - Compatible with other plugins that may use conceal
> - The trailing char can be set to any Unicode char

Comment: If you don't like red, then choose a different color. If you want the color to be compatible with different color schemes, then link to a color group name instead of using a particular color, e.g., `:hi link ExtraWhitespace CursorLine`. See `:help hi-link`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of performance, none of these should make a difference. Vim mostly gets bogged down by complex syntax patterns; the pattern here is quite simple.

To make the highlight color agree with the chosen colorscheme, use `:hi link` to an existing group; usually, that would be `Error`. Of course, any of this only matters if you switch (quite different) colorschemes often; else, using suitable colors directly (as in your solution 1) would be fine, too.

> Solution 1: Manually highlight trailing spaces

I'd go for this, but using `matchadd()` instead of `:match`; this leaves the latter for custom highlighting. Also, `clearmatches()` is too coarse; it deletes *all* matches, and therefore may affect plugins. You can use / have a look at my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) for a clean and powerful implementation (that also includes exceptions for certain filetypes). Yes, it's a much bigger solution, but I haven't notice any impact yet.

> Solution 2: Using list feature

This is a useful feature in itself, and keeping it on permanently has effects on cursor positioning on Tab characters, so I wouldn't recommend that.

> Solution 3: Using conceal feature

That will surely interfere with some syntaxes and plugins using the feature. Bad idea.

Comment: So, from your answer I understand that there is so solution that allow using a custom Unicode char to mark extra spaces. This question is indeed more tricky that I initially thought.

Comment: Right, custom chars only work with `'listchars'`. To me, the highlighting is more than enough (especially with aggressive colors).